# Set y-axis for glm probit regression in effect plot

Tags: r, plot, glm

I am currently computing binomial probit `glm` in `R`.

For analysis of **interaction effects**, I use the `effects` package. I want to plot different interactions, where one of the interacting variables is held constant at a fixed level. I do this for several values of the variable to see how the effect evolves.

I use the following operation:

```
    plot(effect("varL",hx1,given.values=c("varP"=0.7)))
    plot(effect("varL",hx1,given.values=c("varP"=0.1)))
```

However, to graphically compare the different plots, the y-axis should be the same for all plots, which is not the case. When plotting for different `varP` values, the y axis changes its range.

When specifying `ylim`, the plot is also incorrect and shows a completely different segment than specified.

I tried what was recommended in this post ([Scaling axis in a GLM plot with library "effects"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35697833/scaling-axis-in-a-glm-plot-with-library-effects)), however, it resulted in an error message:

```
plot(effect("varL",hx1,given.values=c("varP"=0.7)), ylim = qlogis(c(0, 0.20)))

Error in valid.viewport(x, y, width, height, just, gp, clip, xscale, yscale,  : 
  invalid 'yscale' in viewport
```

Now my question: how can I set the y-axis for plotting interaction effects with the effect package using a probit `glm` model? I am sure the problem is that `ylim` takes the values as specified without adjusting them into the logit and probit scale. `qlogis` likely works for logit, but not probit.

Below some code to replicate the issue. You see that the y axis "jumps around", which I want to avoid.

```
install.packages("effects")
require(effects)

varL <- rnorm(100, mean = 1000, sd = 10)
varP <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
entry <- as.factor(sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))

dat <- data.frame(varL, varP, entry)

hx1 <- glm(entry ~ varL*varP, data = dat, family = binomial(link = "probit"))



plot(effect("varL",hx1,given.values=c("varP"=min(dat$varP))))
plot(effect("varL",hx1,given.values=c("varP"=max(dat$varP))))
```

Here are the plots with the "jumping" y-axes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can run the code and test it ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with logistic regression,actually, and I used the advice [Change the y axis on Effect plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613064/change-the-y-axis-on-effect-plot-in-r)

Basically all that I needed to do is add the argument rescale.axis=F in addition to ylim=c(0,1)